# Oracle equivalent to SQLite's quote() function

Tags: oracle, sqlite, query-optimization

Sometimes I want to generate `INSERT` statements from the contents of a database table.

With SQLite, I can do:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (' || quote(col1) || ',' || quote(col2) || ');'
  FROM bar;
```

With Oracle, I have to do :

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (''' || replace(col1, '''', '''''') || ''',''' || replace(col2, '''', '''''') || ''');'
  FROM bar;
```

And furthermore, it won't work with NULL values.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're on 11g, I'd use [DBMS_ASSERT.ENQUOTE_LITERAL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_assert.htm#BABHBBFH) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I'm on 11.2 and it doesn't seem to do what OP asked. `enquote_literal('a''b')` returns an error, while `enquote_literal('a''''b')` returns `'a''b'` instead of `'a''''b'`

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any problem with nulls in your code.  Where there are nulls the value inserted will be '', which is the same as null in Oracle (I know, I know...) e.g.

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES ('XXX','');
```

and that works.

You could create the QUOTE function in Oracle like this:

```
create function quote (p_text varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
   return '''' || replace (p_text, '''', '''''') || '''';
end;
```

and then your SQLLite SQL will work in Oracle too.

Beware of dates and the default format mask: you will lose any time information in the source table unless you set the default format mask to include it e.g.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

(This needs to be set to the same value when the script is run, too.)

I note Marcus's point about using bind variables, but this seems to me to be one of those one-time scripts that are run and then thrown away, not a bit of production code that will be run over and over, so I don't have a problem with literals.  Tools like Toad and SQL Developer have facilities to generate inserts with literals just like this in fact.

Comment: Thank you. I think the quote function should return `'''' || replace (p_text, '''', '''''') || ''''`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use bind parameters:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/where-clause/bind-parameters

Comment: Not sure it helps me. Bind parameters are, from what I have understood, used when preparing SQL statements in a program, and passing the parameters along with the query.

In this case, I want to generate queries that I can copy-paste to a pure SQL script (to run in Toad, Tora, SQL*Plus or an SQLite shell, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use Q-quote operator introduced in Oracle 10g:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (q''#' || col1 || '#'', q''#' || col2 || '#'');'
  FROM bar;
```

result:

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1, col2) VALUES (q'#col1's value#', q'#col2's value#');
```

Comment: Worth something, but not really safe! Imagine col2 content is `#'); TRUNCATE TABLE foo; --`, what happens?  Moreover, this will only work for importing to an Oracle database…